# Javascript Function factory code need understanding

Tags: javascript, function, factory

I can't understand this code ,especially how value of x in "myfunc" takes up the value when called.... what does thois line of code means "var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);" Please note console returns result 30.

```
// Function factory
function makeMultiplier(multiplier) {
  var myFunc = function (x) {
    return multiplier * x;
  };

  return myFunc;
}

var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
console.log(multiplyBy3(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a good demonstration of JavaScript's [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

When you run:

```
var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
```

`makeMultiplier` is called, which creates a local variable `myFunc`, whose value is a JavaScript function. `myFunc`'s body references `multiplier`, which comes from the parameter to `makeMultiplier(multiplier)`, and `x`, which comes from the function's own parameter `x`.

`makeMultiplier` then returns `myFunc`, which is now a closure since the variable in scope when it was created, namely `multiplier`, is still intact, even though `makeMultiplier` itself has exited.

Now, since the return value of `makeMultiplier(3)` was a function, `multiplyBy3` now has that function as its value. As such, you can now call `multiplyBy3` as a regular function, which is what happens in the next line.

```
console.log(multiplyBy3(10));
```

This line logs the return value of `multiplyBy3`, which was `multiplier * x`.

`x` was just passed in to the function as its only parameter, so `x` is `10`.
`multiplier` is the same as the `multiplier` from the previous call to `makeMultiplier`, so `multiplier` is `3`.

Thus, `multiplyBy3` returns `3 * 10`, which is `30`, which is the output that you see logged in your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

I added a little documentation to the code to help clarify what is going on.

```js
// --------------------
// A function that when executed returns a new function
// --------------------
function makeMultiplier(multiplier) {

  console.log("multiplier for this new function shall be: " + multiplier);

  // --------------------
  // A function that takes a parameter "x" and
  // returns "x" multiplied by "multiplier"
  // --------------------
  var myFunc = function(x) {
    console.log("multiplying " + multiplier + " * " + x);
    return (multiplier  * x);
  };
  // --------------------

  return myFunc;
}
// --------------------

// --------------------
// use makeMultiplier to create a new function
// --------------------
var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
// --------------------

// --------------------
// use our new function
// --------------------
var result = multiplyBy3(10);
// --------------------

console.log("results in " + result);
```